# Run IIS and Kestrel from command line in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I'm entering `dotnet run`, it seems that IIS doesn't work, how can I run it from the console?

I need similar behavior like **IIS Express** button in Visual Studio, which runs all server-side for a project, but start all that commands, which I don't know, from console.